# What are the difference of putting these 2 local variables

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any difference between these 2 ways of declaring local variables? will the second way actually go to global? I have some different components having `const componentName = 'xxxxxx'` across the app, and looks like they are not colliding.

file1.js

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        ...
        this.options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        this.componentName = 'MyComponent';
    }

    ...
}
```

file2.js

```
const options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const componentName = 'MyComponent';
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not try it yourself and find out? (P.S. in the first case, those are instance variables, not local variables.)

Comment: Well, the consts only really exist in the current module because they aren't exported.

Comment: I tried, they are actually not in the window object, that's why I ask. I actually expect they to be there

Comment: To make them global, use `global.<property>` which attaches to Node's `global` object which is global across all modules.

Comment: @AndrewLi The browser does not have an object named `global` (or, for the time being, modules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_modules-in-javascript

from the link:

> 16.2 Modules in JavaScript
>
> Even though JavaScript never had built-in modules, the community has
> converged on a simple style of modules, which is supported by
> libraries in ES5 and earlier. This style has also been adopted by ES6:
>
> Each module is a piece of code that is executed once it is loaded. In
> that code, there may be declarations (variable declarations, function
> declarations, etc.). By default, these declarations stay local to the
> module. You can mark some of them as exports, then other modules can
> import them. A module can import things from other modules. It refers
> to those modules via module specifiers, strings that are either:
> Relative paths ('../model/user'): these paths are interpreted
> relatively to the location of the importing module. The file extension
> .js can usually be omitted. Absolute paths ('/lib/js/helpers'): point
> directly to the file of the module to be imported. Names ('util'):
> What modules names refer to has to be configured. Modules are
> singletons. Even if a module is imported multiple times, only a single
> “instance” of it exists.
>
> **This approach to modules avoids global variables** <--,
>
> **the only things that are global are module specifiers**. <--

**In example 1. You make them part of your Class, so they are available within the instance of the Class (they are not global though), they are part of the instance, because "this" will refer to the instance of the Class, not to the global "window" object. (so at example 1 they are not local variables)**

**In example 2. Your consts will stay local within the module u declared them in**  enless u do something like

```
export const foo = 'bar';  (still not global, but can be imported within other modules)
```

**So thats the difference.**

Another good read: https://joshbedo.github.io/JS-Design-Patterns/
Javascript design patterns (module pattern etc)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for `const`:

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using
>   the let statement.

Referring then to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for `let`:

> At the top level of programs and functions, let, unlike var, does not
>   create a property on the global object.

So as you have noted, even at the top level, `const` will not pollute the global object (`window`).

Comment: then, is there any practical difference those 2 way of placing "private" properties? looks like both just sit inside the module/class

Comment: @Kossel as andrew Li said, in ur second example u don't export the const, so the consts only exist within that module, in your first example they are part of the class, meaning in the first example they are available within the export as part of the class, and within your second example they arent. - meaning they won't go global because they only exist within that module